# Azure VM - RDP - The Login Attempt Failed

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine

When I try to RDP to an Azure VM (Windows Server 2022) I get the error: "The login attempt failed" for AAD users.

It works fine from my old computer but I'm trying to get this working for a new computer. On the new computer I can login fine using the VM local admin account but not my AAD user account. Here are the difference between the two computers.

Old Computer:

- Windows 10 Enterprise
- Azure AD Joined (to same tenant)
- Local Admin VM login works
- AAD user VM login works

New Computer:

- Windows 11 Enterprise
- Azure AD Registered (to same tenant)
- Azure AD Joined (to a different tenant)
- Local Admin VM login works
- AAD user VM login fails

There is an Azure VPN Gateway, which is turned on for both computers.
I've downloaded the RDP file directly from the VM Connect blade.

Why would AAD user login not work?

Answer (score 1):

When I try RDP to an Azure VM, I got the same error like below:

[image]

Created virtual machine with ***Windows server 2022 datacenter*** and  **Login with Azure AD** like below:

[image]

Ensure that `AADLogin extensions` are installed like below:

[image]

When using Azure AD credentials to log into the VM, try to assign the user the RBAC role.

> ***Virtual Machine Administrator Login-*** User assigned to this role, can log in to Azure AD Admin privileges.
> ***Virtual Machine User Login*** -The user assigned this role, can log in with normal user privileges.

[image]

Join the VM to Azure AD Tenant and disconnect from existing AD Connect if you have:

***In RDP -> setting -> account -> add AD user in work or school account like below:***

[image]

Press Win + R to open the Run command Type **`sysdm.cpl`** and Enter -> In system properties **uncheck Network Level Authentication** Like below:

[image]

Now try to assign the user to remote desktop group like below:

```c
net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" /add "AzureAD\u1@gopivallepuoutlook.onmicrosoft.com"
```

[image]

To verify the Azure AD user added:

[image]

In the virtual machine, I start the command prompt and use **`dsregcmd /status.`** The machine is Azure AD Joined.

[image]
[image]

Now sign out from the vm remote desktop and edit the RDP file to connect like below:

```c
enablecredsspsupport:i:0
authentication level:i:2
username:s:XXX@Testdemo.onmicrosoft.com (Add your username here)
domain:s:AzureAD
```

[image]

Now, when I try to login with Azure AD user **`AzureAd\UPN`** logged on successfully like below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Imran, thank you for your detailed response. I've stepped through everything you suggested (twice) and applied the changes. Now when I RDP I get to the server login screen but after entering my credentials I get: "The sign-in method you're trying to use isn't allowed. Try a different sign-in method or contact your system administrator"

Comment: I have MFA on my account. Could that be the cause?

Comment: I just tested with an account without MFA and it works. Thank you Imran, you are brilliant. Do you know if MFA security is supported as I certainly don't want to disable MFA on my account.

Answer (score 0):

I just found another way around this that does not involve disabling NLA and works with MFA. Simply create an RDP file like the following that has `enablerdsaadauth` enabled:

```
full address:s:YOUR-TARGET-HOSTNAME
prompt for credentials:i:1
administrative session:i:1
enablerdsaadauth:i:1
enablecredsspsupport:i:0
authentication level:i:2
username:s:YOUR-USERNAME@YOURDOMAIN.COM
domain:s:AzureAD
redirectclipboard:i:1
```

This pops up an AzureAD sign-in window when connecting to the target system, allowing you to use your AzureAD identity to connect to the target system.

Comment: Hi Guy. Thanks for the tip. I may visit this again. If you have Conditional Access policies then consider the following article.
https://cloudbrothers.info/en/the-case-of-signin-method-isnt-allowed/
Thank you to Fabian Bader for documenting this.